# Mirroring function with apache commons

Tags: java, math

How do you mirror a function on x-Axis in Apache commons math, 
 respectively set `f() = -f()`?

I found out so far, that you can add functions with `FunctionUtils` class and i guess i could

do a workaround by taking some points, set y-values negativ and interpolationg new Function,

but that seems a little cumbersome to me. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You could maybe multiply f by a UnivariateFunction that always returns -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all functions are interfaces in `org.apache.commons.math3.analysis` you can wrap every function you want to invert into an anonymous object implementing that interface.

Here are three examples which should get you started:

```
/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/22929746/1266906
 */
public class MinusFunction {

    public static BivariateFunction invert(final BivariateFunction function) {
        return new BivariateFunction() {
            @Override
            public double value(double x, double y) {
                return - function.value(x,y);
            }
        };
    }

    public static MultivariateFunction invert(final MultivariateFunction function) {
        return new MultivariateFunction() {
            @Override
            public double value(double[] point) {
                return -function.value(point);
            }
        };
    }

    public static MultivariateMatrixFunction invert(final MultivariateMatrixFunction function) {
        return new MultivariateMatrixFunction() {
            @Override
            public double[][] value(double[] point) {
                final double[][] value = function.value(point);
                for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < value[i].length; j++) {
                        value[i][j] = -value[i][j];
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }
        };
    }
}
```